# Can't upload attachment on MoinMoin

Tags: upload, attachment, moinmoin

I have installed MoinMoin on my Windows machine:

MoinMoin 1.9.7,
Python 2.7

However, I can't upload an attachment to any page. I got the following error whenever I click "Upload":

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I've tried Python 2.5 too and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

well, you don't give enough details so one could really help you.

so I can just say that this is unusual. it is unlikely a problem in moinmoin or in python.

maybe some problem with your installation or web server configuration.

maybe have a look into the web server logs.